# is it possible to load a transversal wave with a longitudinal wave

Tags: waves, acoustics

like in communication engineering for sending information what we do,

we take a high frequency carrier and modulate it with the message signal

so can we do the same thing like take a high frequency carrier (transversal wave)

but the message is not transversal wave rather the message is longitudinal wave

say a sound wave

so can we modulate or load a transversal wave with a longitudinal wave ??

also if there is any work on this regard .. kindly post the link also??

Answer (score 0):

That is what FM Radio works on.

So lets say we have an entirely analogue setup - a mic as input (RJ talking for example) and  that being broadcast over a 91 MHz Signal real-time   = Audio wave over a High frequency carrier. There is no digitization as you are not sending 0s and 1s here.

However Digital audio over FM has its advantages since the variations are only either zeros and ones, the amplitude can be made higher so there are no dropped bits. This enables the decoder on the receiver to Maintain hi Fidelity to the original broadcasted signal.

The analogue signals can pickup interference on the way since the source audio signal has very fine variations thus a slight disturbance can alter the signal.